# Aggregative sum of objects belonging to objects residing inside hierarchy structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchy

My problem is similar in a way to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564730/sum-of-child-levels-total-in-a-hierarchy), yet different enough in my understanding.

I have three tables:

1. `Units ([UnitID] int, [UnitParentID] int)`
2. `Students ([StudentID] int, [UnitID] int)`
3. `Events ([EventID] int, [EventTypeID] int, [StudentID] int)`

`Students` belong to units, units are stacked in a hierarchy (tree form - one parent per child), and each student can have events of different types.

I need to sum up the number of events of each type per user, then aggregate for all users in a unit, then aggregate through hierarchy until I reach the mother of all units.

The result should be something like this:
[image: result example]

My tools are SQL Server 2008 and Report Builder 3.
I put up a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/951d5) with sample data for fun.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a "write my code for me" kind of service....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query:

```
;WITH CTE(Id, ParentId, cLevel, Title, ord) AS (
    SELECT 
        u.UnitID, u.UnitParentID, 1, 
        CAST('Unit ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.UnitID) AS varchar(3)) AS varchar(max)),
        CAST(RIGHT('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.UnitID) AS varchar(3)), 3) AS varchar(max))
    FROM 
        dbo.Units u
    WHERE 
        u.UnitParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        u.UnitID, u.UnitParentID, c.cLevel + 1, 
        c.Title + '.' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cLevel ORDER BY c.Id) AS varchar(3)),
        c.ord + RIGHT('000' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.UnitID) AS varchar(3)), 3)
    FROM
        dbo.Units u
        JOIN
        CTE c ON c.Id = u.UnitParentID
    WHERE 
        u.UnitParentID IS NOT NULL
), Units AS (
SELECT 
    u.Id, u.ParentId, u.cLevel, u.Title, u.ord,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventA,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventB,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventC,
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EventD
FROM 
    CTE u
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.Students s ON u.Id = s.UnitId
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.[Events] e ON s.StudentId = e.StudentId
GROUP BY
    u.Id, u.ParentId, u.cLevel, u.Title, u.ord
), addStudents AS (
SELECT *
FROM Units
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    s.StudentId, u.Id, u.cLevel + 1,
    'Student ' + CAST(s.StudentId AS varchar(3)),
    u.ord + RIGHT('000' + CAST(s.StudentId AS varchar(3)), 0),
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN e.EventTypeId = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM Units u
    JOIN
    dbo.Students s ON u.Id = s.UnitId
    LEFT JOIN
    dbo.[Events] e ON s.StudentId = e.StudentId
GROUP BY
    s.StudentID, u.ID, u.cLevel, u.ord
)
SELECT --TOP(10)
    REPLICATE(' ', cLevel) + Title As Title, 
    EventA, EventB, EventC, EventD
FROM
    addStudents 
ORDER BY
    ord
```

For this:

```
Title            | EventA | EventB  | EventC | EventD
-----------------+--------+---------+--------+--------
 Unit 1          | 0      | 1       | 0      | 0
  Student 6      | 0      | 1       | 0      | 0
  Unit 1.1       | 0      | 0       | 0      | 1
   Student 21    | 0      | 0       | 0      | 1
   Student 33    | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0
   Unit 1.1.1    | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0
    Student 23   | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0
    Unit 1.1.1.1 | 3      | 2       | 3      | 0
     Student 10  | 0      | 0       | 0      | 0
     Student 17  | 1      | 0       | 0      | 0
...
```

<kbd>[`SQL Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/951d5/6)</kbd>

Comment: This only sums the events only one level up. I think the idea was to calculate them all the way up to the top.

Comment: @JamesZ I think first CTE will do it ;).

Comment: @shA.t Thanks! But I too don't see how this is aggregating all the way up to top level. More over, I do need to keep the original names of units and students.

Comment: First CTE prepare all levels of `units` with calculating current level of each node is `cLevel` and current sequence of the node as your need in `title` and prepare a field for after ordering as `ord` - Then calculate sums for all `units` in second CTE - In last CTE I add students to results -Then show your expected result, But if you want other fields you can add them to your query ;)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need also the hierarchy to be sorted / visualized? At least this will calculate the sums, but the order of the data is pretty random :)

```
;with CTE as (
  select S.StudentId as UnitID, S.UnitId as UnitParentID,
    S.StudentID, 'Student' as Type
  from Students S
union all
  select U.UnitId, U.UnitParentId, 
    CTE.StudentId as StudentID, 'Unit   ' as Type
  from
    Units U
    join CTE
      on U.UnitId = CTE.UnitParentId
)
select C.Type + ' ' + convert(varchar, C.UnitId), 
  sum(case when EventTypeId = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as E1,
  sum(case when EventTypeId = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as E2,
  sum(case when EventTypeId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as E3,
  sum(case when EventTypeId = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as E4
from 
  CTE C
  left outer join events E on C.StudentId = E.StudentId
group by
  C.Type, C.UnitId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1214/7)

If you need also the hierarchy to be in order, you'll probably have add few extra CTEs to get the numbering from top down with something like @shA.t did. This gathers the hierarchy separately for each student, so it's not really possible to add the level numbers in a simple way.

Comment: Thanks! I do need to visualize the hierarchy.